# How to find abbreviations of 2-4 letters in length in the parenthesis in word

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a word document, I want to select all the abbreviations in it. I tried to use the `advanced search` and check the `wild card`.
However it doesn't show any results with the following code.

`([\(])([A-Z])([\)]){2,4}`

The abbreviation would look like `Apple tree (APt)`, `All trees (AT)` etc

1. The `(APt)` is the abbreviation, with some letters capital and some are simple. But some will only contain capitals (`(AAA)`) and some only simples (`(mm)`).
2. The abbreviation will always be inside two parenthesis `()`

Answer (score 1):

After a couple of hours of pain of trial and error, I found it if anyone wants it.

```
([\(])([A-Z]*[a-z])([\)])
```

Edit: `([\(])(*)([\)])` this updated one can be used to find anything inside parenthesis.
I found this useful as some of my abbreviations were more than 4 letters (sorry, I later realised as my document is very lengthy)

Comment: This will not match abbreviations with only capitals (i.e. `(AAA)` ) and also a capital and more than 1 small letters (i.e. `Abc`)

Answer (score 0):

To make your original search work you might start with

```
\([A-z]{2,4}\)
```

(i.e. the {2,4} needs to come after the thing you need to find 2-4 of)

Then add back any [] you need to make the ( and ) work properly, e.g. you *might* need

```
[\(][A-z]{2,4}[\)]
```

Then add back the grouping () if you need to replace individual groups.

Finally, the separator `,` depends on regional settings - on some systems, you might need `;` instead.

Comment: `[A-z]` matches much more than letters, have a look at an [ascii table](https://www.asciitable.com/).

Comment: @Toto I deliberately did not cover that part on the grounds that the OP might well not have described exactly what character matching was needed. More important to fix the position of the {2,4} and the non-matching of lowercase IMO.

Comment: Instead of `[A-z]`, use `[A-Za-z]` in order to match all letters and nothing else.